# Window switcher (alt+tab) raises all windows

Tags: unity, window

How can I raise all open windows of one application?

Raising one window of an application one at a time is very slow in intuitive. Any short cuts?

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Windows or "Super" key (between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>) for about 5-10 seconds and it will show you a "cheat sheet" of commands. You may be looking for <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (key usually to the left of your 1)